# Need help on pipe delimited text file to json in mule 4

Tags: mule

Input from text file:

```
ID|ACTION|IID|SPK|DSI|OLID|NLD
1 |  M   | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1  | 1
```

Expected output:

```
{
 "source": "PM",
 "Timestamp": "4/10/2018 11:44:55 AM",

     "tes":{
         "id": 1,
         "ac": "M",
         "test": "1",
         "key": "1",
         "id": "1",
         "nid": "1"
     }
 }
```

I tried below code snippet in dataweave but i am getting exception during runtime.

```
<ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="2a7de32c-1b84-4419-826f-8099ce1dc241" >
             <ee:message >
                 <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
 output application/json
 input payload text/csv
 ---
 payload map{
     source:"PM",
     "Timestamp": now() as String {format: "MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss a"},
     "tes":{
     "id":$.ID,
     "action":$.ACTION,
     "IID":$.IID,
     "SPK":$.SPK,
     "DSI":$.DSI,
     "OLID":$.OLID,
     "NID":$.NLD
     }
     }
 ]]></ee:set-payload>
             </ee:message>
         </ee:transform>
```

Message : "You called the function 'map' with these arguments: 1: String ("ID|ACTION|IID|SPK|DSI|OLID|NLD...) 2: Function (($:Any, $$:Any) -> ???)

But it expects arguments of these types: 1: Array 2: Function

5| payload map{ | ... 11| }

Trace: at map (line: 5, column: 3) at main (line: 5, column: 11)" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0 output application/json indent = true input payload text/csv

Comment: Even though it shows compile time error if you run the project it works fine. But it is populating null. If I change the file separator to comma(,) instead pipe(|) it is working fine. Somehow need to change the default file separator. In 3.9 the below setting works but do not know in mule 4                                                     
 <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/csv">
                <dw:reader-property name="separator" value="|"/>
            </dw:input-payload>

Answer (score 1):

In Mule the DataWeave directive input is ignored so it is not useful to set the input mime type. Also you can not set reader properties as in Mule 3.
In Mule 4 you should set the mime type and reader properties at the message source as described in the documentatin page: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule4-user-guide/v/4.1/dataweave-formats#reader_writer_properties
Then you can set the separator reader property for the CSV format to a pipe. Other reader properties are described at https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule4-user-guide/v/4.1/dataweave-formats#reader-properties-for-csv

Comment: This is not entirely true. You can set the input metadata to expect a pipe-delimited csv.

Comment: Metadata is used at design time. The reader properties need to be set for execution time.